# will there be onkeypress event for textbox in asp.net for calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to implement onkeypress event for a textbox in asp.net to call a javascript function that validates textbox for number field. How can i validate a textbox in asp.net for number field using javascript function but that javascript function is not calling.
This is my javascript function

```
function FDigit(x)
{
if (x.KeyCode < 48 || x.KeyCode > 57)
{
    alert("Enter Digits only");
    return false;
}
```

this is my textbox control from where i have called for onkeypress event.

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSalary" runat="server" OnKeyPress="return FDigit(x)"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call function from text input key press in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788896/how-to-call-function-from-text-input-key-press-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `event`to to your function rather than `x`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSalary" runat="server" onkeypress="return FDigit(event);" />
```

In the function, use `keyCode` instead of `KeyCode`:

```
function FDigit(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode < 48 || evt.keyCode > 57) {
        alert("Enter Digits only!");
        return false;
    }
}
```