# How to trigger a button click on key press

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <input type = “reset” onclick=‘outputx()’>
```

I want to trigger the button without me clicking on it when the d key is pressed. Output the function and reset at the same time.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event

Comment: use the [keydown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) and trigger your function

Comment: @Francesco I dont understand what its talking abo  it Im still new to html.  Samuel Thats not what Im talking about. I also want it to reset my forms and output the function at the same time.

Comment: You need to use regular quote mark `"` not smart quotes `“`.

Comment: This is a duplicate question [How to call function from text input key press in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788896/how-to-call-function-from-text-input-key-press-in-javascript)

Comment: You don't trigger the button on the key press ... you trigger the same _function_ from both the button click and the key press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add an event listener to the window. The ASCII code for the letter d is 68.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, true);

function onKeyDown(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 68){
     outputx();
  }
```

}

Comment: how do I trigger the reset button on key press cause wouldnt that just trigger the function

Comment: `keyCode` is deprecated.

Comment: I am not sure whether it would work for inputs, but it certainly work for buttons. Here is what you might want to try : `$('input[type=reset]').trigger('click');`

Answer (score 1):

First, you have smart quotes `“”` instead of straight quotes (""). Never use formatted text when coding.

Next, just set up a `keydown` event handler on the `document` that checks to see if the `d` key was pressed:

```js
function output(){
  console.log("You did it!");
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
   if(event.key === "d"){
     document.querySelector("input[type='reset']").click();
   } 
});
```

```html
<input type = "reset" onclick="output()">
```

Comment: ok the thing with that is it output() but it didnt trigger the reset button?

Comment: @zJqson Sorry, misunderstood your question. The answer is updated. Just call the `click()` method of the button.

Comment: But really, a reset button only works with a `form` so, instead of trying to fake a click to the button, just call the `reset()` method of the form instead and skip the middle-man.

Comment: lmao I only wrote 1/100 of my code to simplify it so it's not confusing and also stackoverflow won't let me paste 100 lines of codes in the website.

Comment: @zJqson I really don't understand your last comment. What does that have to do with what I've written?

Comment: No it's okay I said I have the forms and stuff but I simplify it in stackoverflow. There was display.innerhtml stuff I have to clear thats why I want it on keypress Im also new to javascript so Im just trying to learn how to do it.